# Swap or change columns in Angular Mat Table without re-initializing every component inside the table

Tags: angular, optimization, ngfor, angular-components, mat-table

### The Issue

Mat Tables reload every component in their cells every time the columns change. This creates two problems:

1. The component states are lost
2. Poor performance, as the components all reload at once.

This issue does not effect lists <ul> or plain tables <table>.

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-column-reordering-7tlaig?file=src/app/app.component.html) to demonstrate the issue.

[Stackblitz preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GOUs.png)

### What I've tried

I've tried the trackBy function that can be put into *ngFor, but it didn't work, and I don't think it's applicable in this situation anyway, since the columns are identified by strings, and I don't need the trackBy to keep the component from refiring in the list and table examples. I haven't been able to find anything relating to this issue, there's a lot about ways to change matData so that the table doesn't re render itself, but I'm not even changing the data when this issue comes up.

### What I'm trying to do

The reason this is an issue for me is because I created a Column Filter component, which I want to use in every column in my tables (in a second header row). The column filter component allows users to filter a different string per column. Not only that, it has an options menu where users can specify if they want the results to include the string, not include it, start with it, etc. Plus, I'm adding different data types, so for a column with dates, instead of users typing in to a simple input, they'll be choosing a date range from a calendar. After that, they can then specify if they want the results within the range, outside, before, etc.

[Column Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrW2V.png)

Unfortunately, these components take a bit of time to start up, negligible unless there's more than 3, so when you have a table with 12 columns, each with their own filters, there's 300+ms of lag every time a column is moved or removed.

### The Ideal Solution

Ideally, Mat Tables should be able to re-arrange their columns without destroying and re-creating every component in their cells.

### Possible alternatives

- Try to make the Column Filter components take less time to load.

  - For some reason, taking out the mat-menus in the column filter components speeds them up a whole lot. So I could try using an alternative to those, or implementing them myself, or loading them one at a time.

    - I ended up doing a bit of "lazy loading" for the mat menus. Worked pretty good, lag for a 12 column Mat Table is down from the 300ms range to less than 40ms.

```
// lazy loading code
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="showMenu = true"/>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div *ngIf="showMenu">
    ...
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

- Try to load the column filters one at a time instead of all at once (not really an option)
- See if it works with cdkTable and go from there
- Use a vanilla <table> instead of the Mat Table

  - The most effective alternative is to just not use Mat Tables, but I don't really want to do this because I'm already using the paginator and the matData and data filtering and the formatting and style of the Mat Table, and I'd have to start from square one with all of those. But I might have to if I want better performance. And it seems like Angular's Material components are good looking and work ok for what they do, but when you start trying to add your own fancy functionality to them it doesn't always work out.

Comment: I've dig into you problem and found this: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/766b07ecd9c15b4c110b339b296843328cb27447/src/cdk/table/table.ts#L901-L918
i.e. table explicitly clears the view and rerenders it from the very start. I think you can extend the `MatTable` component and overwrite one or several methods, to make it behave as you want in this situation

Comment: but at first I would really debug the performance of your components that take 300+ ms to startup. it doesn't seem normal to me and some performance bug is hidden there

Comment: Hey Andrei, thanks for the reply. I will definitely take a look at the github and consider implementing my own.

As for the components that take long to start up, it's not that the Column Filter component takes a long time to start up, it's that 22 of them at the same time starting up takes 300+ ms. But even so, they shouldn't each be taking 15 ms to start up, so I started looking into them, and it looks like when I remove the <mat-menu> elements, the start time reduces drastically, to the point where 22 of them starting up only takes like 30ms or something.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14952 probably same root cause as your issue. could you try to disable animations on your list, and see if the pefrormance is better?

Comment: Since _forceRenderDataRows() is private in CdkTable, I started trying to extend CdkTable in the stackblitz. Unfortunately it started yelling at me about installing the package, even though I did numerous times. So I'll have to try that in my own code later.

I tried disabling animations by following [these instructions](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#parent-child-animations), but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: I ended up using lazy loading. Specifically, I put the contents inside the mat-menus in an ngIf like this:
```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="showMenu = true"/>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div *ngIf="showMenu">
    ...
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

It works well enough, the lag is still there but it's in the 30ms range instead of 300, much better. But I've only reduced problem #2 and problem #1 is still there, so I might still look at extending CdkTable (if I can figure out why stackblitz isn't cooperating).